# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Breakpoints'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

I think it’s a general `TypeScript` question.

My goal is to implement a custom `hook` for `useMediaQuery`.
For example, instead of `useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('md');`, I would like to simply write: `useBreakPoint('down', 'md');`

For that I have implemented the `hook` in following way:

```
import {useTheme} from '@material-ui/core';
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery';
import {Breakpoint} from '@material-ui/core/styles/createBreakpoints';

type Limit = 'up' | 'down' | 'between' | 'only';

function useBreakPoint(limit: Limit, breakpoint: Breakpoint): boolean {
    const theme = useTheme();
    return useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints[limit](breakpoint));
}

export default useBreakPoint
```

Unfortunately, compiler is throwing `Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.`-Error for `(parameter) limit: Limit` at me.

It seems that something with `limit` must be an issue.

After a couple of trial-and-error, I observed following weird behavior:

### what works

- `breakpoint["down"]`
- `const limit = "down"; theme.breakpoints[limit];`

### what does not work

- `const limit: string = "down"; theme.breakpoints[limit];`

Error: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Breakpoints'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Breakpoints'` for `const limit: string.

- `function useBreakPoint(limit: keyof Limit, breakpoint: Breakpoint): boolean {`

Error: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number | unique symbol | "toString" | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | "match" | "replace" | "search" | "slice" | "split" | "substring" | ... 34 more ... | "replaceAll"' can't be used to index type 'Breakpoints'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'Breakpoints'`

at: `(parameter) limit: number | typeof Symbol.iterator | "toString" | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | "match" | "replace" | "search" | "slice" | ... 36 more ... | "replaceAll"`.

### `Breakpoints`-interface definition

`Breakpoints`-interface definition looks like this:

```
export interface Breakpoints {
  keys: Breakpoint[];
  values: BreakpointValues;
  up: (key: Breakpoint | number) => string;
  down: (key: Breakpoint | number) => string;
  between: (start: Breakpoint | number, end: Breakpoint | number) => string;
  only: (key: Breakpoint) => string;
  /**
   * @deprecated
   * Use the `values` prop instead
   */
  width: (key: Breakpoint) => number;
}
```

Can anyone explain what the issue with `up`, `down`, `between` and `only` is and what I'm doint wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: The `between` function accepts 2 arguments, hence it breaks. What would you want to pass as a second parameter to this function? ([here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwK4GcCmAVAFmkaC+cAZlBCHAOQACIAhjGlMLQDYC0SwA9AMbRoUA3AChQkWHFRoAsmgAmzAIpJGAT2Kly1OgyasO3PlDRcpshbWVqho8NHgIAQsdoBrSMAB2MQiTKUaekZmdk5efi4UGFUWNBReFwZnNDcPbxQbYWiwNDgAGVBgeABeSiQwCjgAH0o5CAB3T0qaigAjNBh6tDQm6soITxZVTKIkTx4YYAHJdGS3AAUILxgAChZCmAAufI2AGjhWl3cl72254+WASm3WiAhY2k9EYThXuD5PKLgYHDw4Uqk2FwaBWlxEbzgxhgSCgTzM8iUKigqhWP2BADpDikLukANrrEBFAC6KyxqROMH2ZJxMEuYOE+CAA) is a working, but stupid fix)

Comment: the type of limit should be keyof theme.breakpoint type if you have it

Comment: @NicolasMenettrier: yes, I can import `Breakpoints` type from `@material-ui/core/styles/createBreakpoints`. And with `limit: keyof Breakpoints`, compiler complains: This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type '((key: number | Breakpoint) => string) | ((key: number | Breakpoint) => string) | ((start: number | Breakpoint, end: number | Breakpoint) => string) | ((key: Breakpoint) => string) | Breakpoint[] | BreakpointValues | ((key: Breakpoint) => number)' are callable.
    Type 'Breakpoint[]' has no call signatures. for `(parameter) limit: keyof Breakpoints`

Comment: @A_A that was it. Thank you for pointing out and making me aware that `between` accepts 2 arguments. I totally missed that. I think I would go for following implementation:

`function useBreakPoint(limit: Limit, start: Breakpoint, end?: Breakpoint): boolean {
    const theme = useTheme();
    return useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints[limit](start, end || start));
}`.

I'd be happy to accept your answer as the solution if you posted your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type Limit = 'up' | 'down' | 'between' | 'only';` is fine, but you have to

either (1) add one more argument to `theme.breakpoints[limit](breakpoint)` like `theme.breakpoints[limit](breakpoint, 1)` (as an example) to make the function call compatible to all of

```
  up: (key: Breakpoint | number) => string;
  down: (key: Breakpoint | number) => string;
  between: (start: Breakpoint | number, end: Breakpoint | number) => string;
  only: (key: Breakpoint) => string;
```

or (2) make `end` parameter in `between` method optional

```
  up: (key: Breakpoint | number) => string;
  down: (key: Breakpoint | number) => string;
  between: (start: Breakpoint | number, end?: Breakpoint | number) => string;
  only: (key: Breakpoint) => string;
```

or (3) handle `'between'` case differently due to incompatible call signature

```
return useMediaQuery(
  limit === 'between'
    ? theme.breakpoints[limit](breakpoint, 1)
    : theme.breakpoints[limit](breakpoint)
);
```